# can't play videos in totem - error says that we're missing plugins that should not be missing

Tags: 13.04, video-player, error-handling

Relevant: During install I already clicked the box to allow restricted content. Recently I also installed ubuntu-restricted extras. These videos used to work on previous install with no problem. Formats are mp4, webm, and avi.

The error is "Totem could not startup. Some necessary plug-ins are missing. Make sure that the program is correctly installed".

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall totem` to reinstall Totem and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 7):

VLC

This would allow you to watch videos and listen to music but doesn't fix a very serious problem with totem & gstreamer:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0
```

This is overkill, actually intended to remove `~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.[cpu_arch].bin`

But it's harmless. It just removes cache files that will be regenerated as soon as you use gstreamer again (in totem or whatever). The idea is that your cache may somehow be corrupt and pointing to the plugins in the wrong place. There are no theories as to how this can happen or why this fix works, but it works for some people.

Not for me :)

Comment: Don't know why, but it works!

Comment: This fixed it on Ubuntu 23.10 as well! Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

```
rm -r ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0
```

This is the fix. Hope it works

Comment: Could you explain *what* is being removed here and *why* this would fix it? I'm usually not blindly following advice that's about removing files. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**After installing these packages, totem started working without any problems...**

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-xapp-1.0 python3-psutil
```

Run command,reboot your system and watch your videos.

Answer (score -1):

If edwin's solution doesn't work you should download VLC in Ubuntu Softwarecenter. This program allows almost every format (audio and video) to open without problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras --reinstall`

Comment: What you expect to solve with this?